# Is the potential at the middle of depletion layer of p-n junction diode zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

One of my Homework Questions was about describing the Electric Field and Potential at the middle of depletion layer.

I used simple electrostatics to conclude that the potential must be zero and electric field must be minimum at the middle of depletion layer.(Assuming equal magnitude of charge on P side and N side of semiconductor.)

But the answer states that the electric field is maximum!

How can this be? Is the answer just plain wrong? Are my conclusions correct?

Comment: The field across a capacitor gap is constant - the Volts per meter is what it is. Similarly, the field across the depletion layer is pretty much like across a capacitor.

Comment: That is because the width of depletion layer is negligible in comparison to the area of cross section?

Comment: Also assuming potential at infinity to be zero, then field at the middle of depletion layer should be zero?